# WP7: Two parallel TextBlocks with a "fluid" layout

Tags: windows-phone-7, textblock

How to create a layout like this? It has two textblocks that are next to each other, on the same line. Both (or at least the latter one) have textwrap in them.

Stackpanel doesn't seem to work, because it will leave a wide margin on the left for the 2nd textblock - the same with a Grid. Those look like two columns. I'd like the textblock2 to flow below the textblock1.

[image: Two textblocks]

Comment: I ended up using RichTextBox with a Paragraph inside it and Paragraph.Inlines having the text blocks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use a **WrapPanel** (In the [WP7 ToolKit](http://silverlight.codeplex.com/releases/view/75888))

You'll basically have a WrapPanel with 2 TextBlocks in it and it will do exactly what you want

Answer (score 3):

You might want to alternatively have a look at [`TextBlock.Inlines`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.textblock.inlines%28v=vs.95%29.aspx):

```
<TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap">
    <TextBlock.Inlines>
        <Run Text="TEXTBLOCK1 " FontWeight="Bold" />
        <Run Text="TEXTBLOCK2 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing..." />
    </TextBlock.Inlines>
</TextBlock>
```

It should work for your purposes since Silverlight uses the entire TextBlock to calculate layout and overflow.

Comment: Thanks, it's a toss between these two suggestions.

Comment: No worries, keep in mind that inlines would be faster than using a wrappanel as WrapPanel needs to layout their children as well as itself. Inlines are all managed by TextBlock. If you've gone with WrapPanel don't change it, but keep it in mind if you are having layout-related performance issues on that page.